# Detecting Mouse Over Dock, Any Dock Icon Click

Tags: objective-c, macos, dock

Is there any way of detecting when a user has moused over ANY icon on the dock? Furthermore, is there any way of detecting when a user has clicked ANY icon on the dock?

There must be a way that hover is detected, since App Store apps like hyperdock and dockview do it. Anyone know how, and if you do...do you know how to detect if a click has been done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use the accesibility API's and something like [NSAccessibilityFocusedUIElementChangedNotification](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSAccessibility_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/data/NSAccessibilityFocusedUIElementChangedNotification) to see when something is hovered over in the dock.  I've never done it though, so I can't give you any details.  Sorry.